# Mostrar datos segun condicion MySQL

Tags: mysql

De nuevo yo con mis consultas en MySQL. Ahora tengo la siguiente consulta...

```
SELECT n.nid, n.type, n.title
FROM node n
INNER JOIN field_data_field_fecha_de_publicaci_n t_fp ON t_fp.entity_id = n.nid
INNER JOIN taxonomy_index t_index ON t_index.nid = n.nid AND t_index.tid = '4'
WHERE t_fp.field_fecha_de_publicaci_n_value <= '2020-08-06 15:07:00' AND n.type IN('foto','podcast','video', 'articulo')
ORDER by n.nid DESC
LIMIT 0, 3
```

Que me da como resultado lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El punto es que si `type = 'articulo'` debe hacer una validación para que se pueda mostrar la cual es, buscar en la tabla `field_data_field_agregar_video` que el campo `field_agregar_video_value = 1`. Ambas tablas comparten el mismo campo en comun: `nid`.

Si `field_agregar_video_value = 1` se muestra el registro, sino, no se muestra pero siempre deben ser 3 registros.

Habia agregado esta línea justo debajo del segundo `INNER JOIN` pero de ahí en adelante solo me muestra los que son `type = 'articulo'`

```
INNER JOIN field_data_field_agregar_video t_av ON t_av.entity_id = n.nid AND t_av.field_agregar_video_value = '1'
```

Quite el `LIMIT` para que vieran mejor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no termino de entender tu problema

Comment: Si en el resultado hay alguno que sea tipo articulo, debe tener la condición que agregar video sea igual a 1, si no lo es, no lo debe mostrar. Al agregar el INNER JOIN del field_data_field_agregar_video me deja de mostrar los otros tipos de contenidos (videos, fotos, etc) y me muestra solo los tipo articulo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no te entendí mal, en el caso de los `articulos`, se requiere una condición adicional que es `field_agregar_video_value = 1`, esto lo manejas en `WHERE` considerando las dos posibilidades (a) Que sea 'articulo' y f`ield_agregar_video_value = 1` o (b) Que NO sea 'articulo'

```
SELECT n.nid, n.type, n.title
       FROM node n
       INNER JOIN field_data_field_fecha_de_publicaci_n t_fp 
             ON t_fp.entity_id = n.nid
       INNER JOIN taxonomy_index t_index 
             ON t_index.nid = n.nid AND t_index.tid = '4'
       WHERE t_fp.field_fecha_de_publicaci_n_value <= '2020-08-06 15:07:00' 
             AND n.type IN('foto','podcast','video', 'articulo')
             AND (
                     (n.type = 'articulo' AND field_agregar_video_value = 1)
                     OR
                     (n.type <> 'articulo')
                 )
       ORDER by n.nid DESC
       LIMIT 0, 3
```

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba. Muchas gracias por tu aporte.